# Changing the Font of the Window Title of the Extension Window

Tags: c#

I have some visual studio extension windows in my project. The Window Title for the extension window is dynamically by using `this.Caption` attribute. I am looking at changing the Font Weight and the Font Size of that Window Title.

Caption attribute doesn’t have any sub functions for it to modify the font weight or the font size. It has only common function like replace, length etc,.

I tried using `Font` class in `System.Drawing` namespace and it doesn’t work on the window title([as suggested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font)). And also, I tried using the Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Font and Colors. Changing Environment’s Plain text size changes the font styling of all the attributes in visual studio along with the Window’s Title.

[image: Image of the one we have tried. Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Font and Colors]

How can I change the font styling of the Window Title manually? Or If possible, how can I change the window’s title font styling programmatically?

Below is the Code I have used for this.Caption

```
[Guid("E10E3419-325A-4F9E-AFED-BE1C1AD8BCBF")]
    public class Window1 : ToolWindowPane
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Window1"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public Window1() : base(null)
        {
            this.Caption = "Window1";
            this.Content = ContextData.Window1_ViewControl;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is "extension window"? What kind of project (e.g. winforms, wpf, etc.)? Are you making VS IDE extension or using one? Do you have a screenshot with `this.Caption` title to show?

Comment: Hi Sinatr, By extension window – I mean that the window is a custom one making use of VS IDE extension. Which can be launched from Visual Studio Menu. We are working on a wpf project. Below is the code I have used for this.caption 

 public class Window1 : ToolWindowPane 

{ 

/// <summary> 

/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref=”Windoe1”/> class. 

/// </summary> 

public Window1() : base(null) 

{ 

this.Caption = “Window1”;  

 

Thanks in Advance.